# Is there any specific difference in code for odoo 8 and odoo 9 custom module developement?

Tags: module, odoo-8, odoo-9

I have developed one custom module in Odoo v8 and I want the same module to work on Odoo v9, is it possible to do this??

Comment: Both are basically similar except some differences ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regading: **Is there any specific difference in code for odoo 8 and odoo 9**
My Answer is **YES**,

***You can't just put module developed for odoo8 in odoo9 addons it will not work.***

There are  major changes in ODOO9, i have find some difference in the module/model:

1. In Stock
2. In Payment
3. in Delivery
4. Website Editor
5. Mail (email.template is replace with mail.template )

For the developer point of view i have found many changes in js also, we using the backbone.js instead of raw js/jquery .

1. Js [use doo.define and requires.js]
2. jsonRpc is now called using require('web.ajax');
   Some controller and method  have  the number of parameter

Overall ODOO9 have the implementation of   more structured and pythonic  code  .

Hope this may help you in understanding the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what should I do basically if I want to run odoo 8 custom module in odoo 9??

Comment: for making the compatibility , start form  inherited view. i can't recommend  you a sliver bullet, as the compatibility issue is particular for module to module,